# Custom CSS for mobile site

Tags: theme, css, mobile

I am currently running my magento site with the responsive
[Ultimo Theme](https://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798), which has been great so far. However, i am wanting to make some custom css changes to hide some elements on my site which are not compatible with my mobile view. How do i go about implementing a custom css file which is only active when my site is being read on a mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should already be a custom CSS file in skin/frontend/ultimo/custom.css or somewhere in that area.

Then use media queries such as:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: can i put multiplemcustom css changes into this query?

Comment: You can put as many as you want yes

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation of the Ultimo theme, you can add css classes to your elements like `hidden-sm hidden-xs` This will hide the element on smaller screens. You have the choice of xs (xtra small - phone), sm, md, lg you can also use `visible-xs visible-sm` to allow certain elements to be shown at various viewport dimensions